# Tell dependent function in conditional statement branch that condition is true

Tags: idris

I have a function with a type signature `(x, y : SomeType) -> (cond x y) = True -> SomeType`. When I check the condition in if-then-else/case/with statement, how do I pass to the function in a corresponding branch the fact, that condition is true?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `DecEq` to make this easy:

```
add : (x, y : Nat) -> x + y < 10 = True -> Nat
add x y _ = x + y

main : IO ()
main =
  let x = S Z
  in let y = Z
  in case decEq (x + y < 10) True of
          Yes prf => print (add x y prf)
          No _ => putStrLn "x + y is not less than 10"
```

But you shouldn't.

Using booleans (via [`=`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/prelude_doc/docs/[builtins].html#=) or [`So`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Bool.html#Prelude.Bool.so)) can tell you that something is true, but not *why*. The *why* is very important if you want to compose proofs together or break them apart. Imagine if `add` called a function which needed `x + y < 20` - we can't just pass our proof that `x + y < 10 = True` because Idris knows nothing about the operation, just that it's true.

Instead, you should write the above with a data type which contains *why* it's true. [`LTE`](http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.Nat.html#Prelude.Nat.LTE) is a type which does that for less-than comparisons:

```
add : (x, y : Nat) -> LTE (x + y) 10 -> Nat
add x y _ = x + y

main : IO ()
main =
  let x = S Z
  in let y = Z
  in case isLTE (x + y) 10 of
          Yes prf => print (add x y prf)
          No _ => putStrLn "x + y is not less than 10"
```

Now, if `add` called a function which needed a `LTE (x + y) 20` we can write a function to widen the constraint:

```
widen : a `LTE` b -> (c : Nat) -> a `LTE` (b + c)
widen LTEZero c = LTEZero
widen (LTESucc x) c = LTESucc (widen x c)
```

This is not something we can easily do with just booleans.